# flatten terraform list of list using for loop without using flatten function

Tags: terraform, hcl

> I know my expected result can be made using **flatten** built in function( which I have given below).
> But I want to know is there any way to create them only using nested
> for loops.

```
  output "languages" {
  value = flatten([ 
    for user in var.users: [
      for language in user.languages: language
    ]
  ])
}
```

**This is my variable**

```
variable "users" {

  default = {
   
    "sam" = {
      "name" = "sam"
      "age"  = 22
      "languages" = ["python","nodejs","perl","ruby"]
      
    },
    "john" = {
      "name" = "john"
      "age"  = 36
      "languages" = ["python","html","cpp","golang","perl","ruby"] 
    },
    "kevin" = {
      "name" = "kevin"
      "age"  = 30
      "languages" = ["python","nodejs","bash","cpp","ruby"] 
    },
    "devid" = {
      "name" = "devid"
      "age"  = 40
      "languages" = ["python","bash","perl","ruby"] 
    },
    "devon" = {
      "name" = "devon"
      "age"  = 25
      "languages" = ["python"] 
    },
    "jain" = {
      "name" = "jain"
      "age"  = 42
      "languages" = ["python","bash","perl","ruby"] 
    }

  } }
```

**This is mycode**

```
output "languages" {
  value = [ 
    for user in var.users: [
      for language in user.languages: language
    ]
  ]
}
```

**Current Result**

```
languages = [
  [
    "python",
    "bash",
    "perl",
    "ruby",
  ],
  [
    "python",
  ],
  [
    "python",
    "bash",
    "perl",
    "ruby",
  ],
  [
    "python",
    "html",
    "cpp",
    "golang",
    "perl",
    "ruby",
  ],
  [
    "python",
    "nodejs",
    "bash",
    "cpp",
    "ruby",
  ],
  [
    "python",
    "nodejs",
    "perl",
    "ruby",
  ],
]
```

**Excepted  Result**

```
languages = [
    "python",
    "bash",
    "perl",
    "ruby",
    "python",
    "python",
    "bash",
    "perl",
    "ruby",
    "python",
    "html",
    "cpp",
    "golang",
    "perl",
    "ruby",
    "python",
    "nodejs",
    "bash",
    "cpp",
    "ruby",
    "python",
    "nodejs",
    "perl",
    "ruby",

]
```

Comment: I have only one question: why do you want that?

Comment: Hi, I just want to know whether it is possible or not , academic interest only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want, but without using `flatten` function you can accomplish something similar with a `for` loop, `concat` and with the [ellipsis](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments) expression:

```
output "languages" {
  value = concat([for item in var.users : item.languages]...)
}
```

The output result will be the following:

```
languages = [
  "python",
  "bash",
  "perl",
  "ruby",
  "python",
  "python",
  "bash",
  "perl",
  "ruby",
  "python",
  "html",
  "cpp",
  "golang",
  "perl",
  "ruby",
  "python",
  "nodejs",
  "bash",
  "cpp",
  "ruby",
  "python",
  "nodejs",
  "perl",
  "ruby",
]
```

Keep in mind, Terraform mainly relies on using [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Moreover, while you can have local variables, they cannot act as intermediary in case of loops and expressions.

Comment: Thanks Brother. So its not possible to create the intended result only using two for loops, I mean without any built in function.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Each `for` expression always constructs either a new tuple or a new object. There is no way to use two `for` expressions together to construct a single tuple or object.

The `flatten` function *is* the way to achieve this in the Terraform language. Although there are other functions that can potentially achieve a similar result, the `flatten` function is the one designed for this purpose and the one idiomatic to use, so is the one that other readers of your configuration will probably find most intuitive if they are familiar with Terraform from elsewhere.